# Is it possible to change the way Xcode indents comment blocks?

Tags: xcode, customization, indentation, comments

By default, Xcode automatically indents multiple lines of code within C-style comment blocks by one space:

```
/* this is a comment block
 line 1
 line 2
*/
```

Is it possible to modify this behaviour? I would prefer to have no indentation within comment blocks.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer, but Xcode has code formatting options under the key [XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW40)

You can set the options via command line or by editing the plist:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict PreExpressionsSpacing  "" PreCommaSpacing " "
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find any setting for the one space indentation in comment blocks, and it makes me crazy!