# Is it possible to change the way Xcode indents comment lines?

Tags: c++, xcode, comments, shortcut

```
      cout<<"hello"<<endl;        //line1
//    cout<<"hello"<<endl;        //line2
      //    cout<<"hello"<<endl;  //line3
      //cout<<"hello"<<endl;      //line4
      //                                        cout<<"hello"<<endl; //line 5
```

I write the line1.

Then I comment line1 using command+/, it becomes line2.

But when I Re-Indent line2 using control+I (Or pasting the line to another place in Xcode), It becomes line3.

I think the blank after "//" is very ugly in line3. Sometimes it will be very long such as line 5.

So I want to know is there a shortcut to comment the line1 to line4, so it will not be inflounced by Re-Indent or Paste?

---

Update:

[Is it possible to change the way Xcode indents comment blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218729/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-xcode-indents-comment-blocks)

I try this command from this answer in command line. And reboot Xcode and system.

But It still get line3.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseFormattingOptions -dict PreExpressionsSpacing  "" PreCommaSpacing " "
```

I want to change the way xcode indents comment "line", not "blocks"
So, this question is different from mine. And it can not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the way Xcode indents comment blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218729/is-it-possible-to-change-the-way-xcode-indents-comment-blocks)

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Thank you. I try it but still get line3. I add this in update.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Xcode extension](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/comment-here/id1406737173?mt=12) for commenting just before indented code.

It makes like

```
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;        //line1
    // cout<<"hello"<<endl;     //line2`
```

So a indent of commented block is not changed even after re-indent